# Statistics that shows how two ranges of numbers overlap?

Tags: data-visualization

I have collected ratings on a scale from 0 to 100 for two different conditions: A and B. I want to show now, that the ratings collected under both conditions are very similar and that their range overlap.

How can I do that best? I thought about drawing a box plot for both conditions, but I would prefer a number / numbers to show.

Comment: how about plotting them on a histogram, you could also add descriptive statistics as desired, e.g, mean, mode, median, st dev

Answer (score 1):

[The Bhattacharyya distance](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bhattacharyya_distance) is a coefficient in the [0;1] range showing the overlap between two probability distributions. Intuitively, it seems to give the answer you desire.

Comment: Although I think this *could* answer this (dated) question, the Bhattacharyya distance is a measure of **dissimilarity** (distance between two probability distributions). As I'd have to assume the OP specifically asked for showing **similarity** when looking at the question, IMO it does not completely answer the question. If you (@abaumann) could expand this answer with how you'd use Bhattacharyya distance to show similarity, I feel the effort would be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the numbers from the box plot, that is a table with the minimum, 25 percentile, 50 percentile (median), 75 percentile, and maximum? Alternatively, you could simply say what percentage of X values lie in the range of observed Y values.